# Что быстрее при использовании много if, if-else или switch

Tags: java, android

В проекте есть много ситуаций где нужно проверить выбранное действие.

Что оптимальнее использовать:

**Много If**

```
if (...){}
if (...){}
if (...){}
```

**If-else**

```
if (...){}
else if (...){}
else if (...){}
else if (...){}
...
```

**Switch**

```
switch(...){
    case ONE:
        break;
    case TWO:
        break;
    case THREE:
        break;
    ...
       ...
    case N:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос относится к преждевременной оптимизации :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оператор `switch`, как правило (то есть когда нетривиальный, в тривиальных случаях JIT его разберет на `if/else`) - транслируется в байткод `tableswitch` или `lookupswitch`

Производительность `tableswitch` **O(1)**, а `lookupswith` **O(log N)** (то есть сравним с `if/else/if`)

**P.S.** [перечень байткод инструкций](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html)

Answer (score 12):

Подобного рода оптимизации бесполезны, так как JIT-компилятор всё равно делает их лучше вас. Поэтому оптимальнее использовать то, что делает код чище и проще для сопровождения.

Comment: К тому же JIT может создать в итоге разный код в зависимости от типа проверяемого параметра.